# VizFrame: dataPointStyle properties aren't applied to data

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm working with VizFrame (`sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame`) of SAPUI5 and I'm trying to get a line of a time series line chart (`timeseries_line`) dashed.

My dataset (shorted):

```
<viz:dataset>
    <viz.data:measures>
        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Threshold" value="{THRESHOLD}" />
    </viz.data:measures>
</viz:dataset>
```

My feeds (shorted):

```
<viz:feeds>
    <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Threshold" />
</viz:feeds>
```

And my `VizProperties`:

```
                    plotArea : {
                      dataPointStyleMode: "update",
                      dataPointStyle : {
                          rules: [{
                           dataContext: {"THRESHOLD": "*"},
                           properties: {
                                color: "#EACF5E",
                                lineType: "dash"
                            },
                            displayName: "Threshold",
                            dataName: {
                                "THRESHOLD": "Threshold"
                            }}]
                          }
                      }
```

The problem is that the threshold line isn't dashed or colored after calling `setVizProperties` with the `plotArea` of above. But it adds Threshold with dashed line to the legend. What's wrong here?

Hint: I also tried `"Threshold": "*"` as data context. The `dataPointStyleMode` of `override` also won't work (then it's black and solid).